# I need to vlookup in Excel for a word in a string and return a value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a long list of job titles and a table with certain keywords and scores for those keywords. I need to see if any of the keywords is in the different job titles and if so, return the score for that keyword.

For example, I have the job title in cell `D5` = *Senior Digital Marketing Specialist*

Then I have a table

```
|Column G          |Column H|
|digital marketing |1       |
|e-commerce        |2       |
|campaign          |3       |
```

Since "Digital Marketing" is in `D5`, I need to return the value "1" from column `H`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
=INDEX(L:L,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($K$1:$K$3)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($K$1:$K$3,D5))),1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your data is organized in a table format with columns and rows.
Identify the column that contains the string you want to search in (let's call it the Search Column) and the column that contains the corresponding values you want to retrieve (let's call it the Return Column).
In a cell where you want to display the result, enter the formula: `=VLOOKUP("word", SearchColumnRange, ReturnColumnNumber, 0)`.

Comment: To perform a VLOOKUP in Excel for a word within a string and return a value, you can use a combination of functions like VLOOKUP, IF, and SEARCH. Here's an example formula:

l
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("word", A2)), VLOOKUP("word", lookup_range, column_index, 0), "Not Found")